# Estou Criando um Navigation Drawer no android studio e não consigo setar os cliques nos itens

Tags: android, menu, navigation-drawer

A main Activity:

```
package com.example.italo.nvigationdrawer;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private NavigationView navigationView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.open_drawer,R.string.close_drawer);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);

    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menu_inbox:{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Menu Inbox" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }

        case R.id.menu_starred:{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Menu Favoritos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
        case R.id.menu_sent_email:{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Menu Enviados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }

        case R.id.menu_trash:{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Menu Lixeira", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }

        case R.id.menu_spam:{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Menu Spam", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }

    }

    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

XML DA ACTIVITY

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_nav"
    />


<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
```

A Classe do menu em si:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">

    <item android:title="@string/inbox"
        android:id="@+id/menu_inbox"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_inbox"/>

    <item android:title="@string/favoritos"
        android:id="@+id/menu_starred"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_starred"/>

    <item android:title="@string/emails_enviados"
        android:id="@+id/menu_sent_email"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_sent_email"/>

</group>

<item android:title="@string/outros"
    android:id="@+id/submenu_outros">

    <menu>

        <item android:title="@string/lixeira"
            android:id="@+id/menu_trash"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_trash"/>

        <item android:title="@string/spam"
            android:id="@+id/menu_spam"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_spam"/>

    </menu>

</item>
```

Comment: Poste o código xml da sua activity

Comment: Prontinho esta ai em cima